# Python pipe in binary file from command line -u option

Tags: python

Is there a decoupled method of passing in a binary file without suffering the penalty of python having unbuffered stdout for the entire duration of running a program (if i intend to use only cmdline and not open(...,'rb')?  It seems like -u is the only way to read in a file as binary data (from cmdline)

http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html

-u    Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "decoupled" here?

Comment: for some reason, python has -u (unbuffered output which makes things very slow), also control whether or not a file in operator such as test.py < myfile is treated as binary input.  i ran into a problem in which I had to use this input format for a class and in the process of parsing the file, it would read the equivalent of 'ctrl+z' and kill the application. so my hope was that there's a way to treat a file as binary in, w/o telling python to have unbuffered output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps avoid Python's file mode by instead grabbing the fileno out of the `sys.stdin` file-like object, and using [`os.read()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.read) to grab data from it?

```
import os
import sys

stdin_no = sys.stdin.fileno()
some_bytes = os.read(stdin_no, 1024)
```

Comment: as a follow up to satisfy my own curiosity, do you know why python would tie two unrelated things together as a single cmdline op?

Comment: I don't know offhand, no - my guess would be because they assumed that most people who wanted unbuffered input would also want binary input.

Answer (score 0):

This code will change standard input (only) to unbuffered mode.  Using this you will not need to invoke the interpreter with `-u`.  Unix only.

```
import fcntl, os, sys

def set_fd_nonblocking(fd):
  u"put an open file descriptor into non-blocking I/O mode"
  if fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK) != 0:
    raise IOError, "can't set file descriptor %s option O_NONBLOCK" % (fd,)

set_fd_nonblocking(sys.stdin.fileno())
```

However I am unsure what side effects this could have, for example on the `raw_input` built-in function.

Be careful; even in non-blocking mode, if `select` tells you the fd is ready to read you will still need to catch `OSError` and check for `e.errno == os.errno.EAGAIN`.  Such errors should be ignored.